# Disable email notification to sub-folders in the exchange account

Tags: notifications, exchange

I have a number of sub-folders set up on my exchange email account with rules moving certain emails into these folders automatically. How can I disable notification for new email for those specific sub-folders?
**I would like to keep using the default Android app for exchange.**